# Characters corrupted when inserted in database

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a PHP script that gets a XML, selects some data, and insert them in my database (MySQL). All my fields are utf8_bin. This XML is ISO-8859-1, and can't change this because is another site that sends it to me.

Example: the string "NG Contábil" is set "NG ContÃ¡bil" in my db. This is my script:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_client=utf8');
mysql_query('SET character_set_results=utf8');

include '/PagSeguroLibrary/PagSeguroLibrary.php';
include '/PagSeguroLibrary/domain/PagSeguroAccountCredentials.class.php';
include 'conexao.php';
include 'alias_array.php';
include 'retorna_cpf.php';

$conexao = ConectaBD::get_instance();
$conexao->conectar_pronto();
$conexao->BD_pronto();

//(...)

$xml = simplexml_load_file('arquivo.xml');

if($xml === null)
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($resposta_transacao);

$status = $xml->status;
$nome = $xml->sender->name;
$email = $xml->sender->email;
$codigo = $xml->code;
$vetor = $xml->items->item;

$cpf = retorna_cpf($email);

foreach($vetor as $v)
{
    $nome_produto = $v->description;

    if($nome_produto != 'frete')
    {
        //Retorna o id do produto a partir da descrição
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT id_product
        FROM ps_product_lang
        WHERE name = "'.$nome_produto.'"');

        $array = Array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_alias_array($result))
        {
            foreach($row as $linha)
                array_push($array, $linha);
        }         

        mysql_query('INSERT INTO pagamento(Status, Nome, Email, CPF, idproduto, Codigo, Inscrito, id, Enviado, NomeProduto) 
        VALUES ("'.$status.'", "'.$nome.'", "'.$email.'", "'.$cpf.'", "'.$array[0].'", "'.$codigo.'", 0, null, 0, "'.$nome_produto.'")');
    }
    }
fclose($arquivo);
unlink('arquivo.xml');
?>
```

Thanks for any answer!

Comment: Can you paste the first couple of lines from your XML?

Comment: Is it `utf8` or `utf-8`?

Comment: I also had a same problem .. using mysql_set_charset() solved my problem ... http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php have a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have overlooked just one little nuance:
`mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` is not a magical spell that have to be cast in order to make proper encoding, but actually an SQL query, which needs to be run **in the same instance** you are actually using to run SQL queries.

So, if you are connecting to your mysql database using ConectaBD::get_instance(); you have to run `SET NAMES utf8` query **after** that call, not before.

> I don't know why, but adding utf8_decode() solves the problem

I know.
`simplexml`'s output is **always** utf-8.
While, as I pointed out above, you don't set your client connection into `utf8`.
So, it remains default `latin1`
With (quite useless) utf8_decode() call you're casting your `utf-8` data back into `latin1` and thus it correctly stored into database.

Answer (score 1):

This should solve your issue:

```
...
$xml = simplexml_load_file('arquivo.xml');
$xml = iconv('ISO-8859-1', 'UTF-8', $xml);
...
```